I have a Kendo Grid and need to save Grid Data to Excel sheet Where the Excel Sheet is Protected
function ExportExcelTemplateClicked() {
    var grid = $('#DocumentGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    var columnHeaders = [];

    $(_registerColumns).each(function (index, column) {
        if (column.ColumnType !== 6) {
            console.log(column)
            columnHeaders.push({ value: column.ColumnTitle, background: "#7D7C7C", editable: false });
        }
    });

    var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
        sheets: [
            {
                columns: columnHeaders.map(function (header) {
                    return { autoWidth: true };
                }),
                rows: [
                    {
                        cells: [{ value: "Document No.", editable: false }, { value: '@Model.DocumentNo', editable: false }],
                        height: 30
                    },
                    {
                        cells: [{ value: "Rig Name", editable: false }, { value: '@Model.WorkUnitName', editable: false }],
                        height: 30
                    },
                    {
                        cells: [{ value: "Subject", editable: false }, { value: '@Model.Subject', editable: false }],
                        height: 30
                    },
                    {
                        cells: [{ value: '',  editable: false }, { value: '', editable: false }],
                        height: 20
                    },
                    {
                        cells: columnHeaders
                    }
                ],
                editable: false
            }
        ]
    });

    kendo.saveAs({
        dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(),
        fileName: "Register Rows-" + '@Model.DocumentNo' + ".xlsx"
    });

    SystemNotification("Alert", "Make sure not to make any changes to the Register Details or Column Headers.");
}

Excel File is Generated but the Columns and Register Details is Editable
